# Why is my console not printing the message after every minute passed, does useEffect hook runs only once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, console

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function DigitalClock() {
  const[currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(new Date());
  useEffect(()=>{
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
      setCurrentTime(new Date());
    },1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  },[]);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const second = currentTime.getSeconds();
    if(second===0){
      console.log("another minute passed");
    }
  },[currentTime])
  const formattedTime = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString();
  return(
    <h2>{formattedTime}</h2>
  )
}

export default DigitalClock;
```

IN THIS I WANT TO MAKE A CONSOLE.LOG AFTER EVERY MINUTE PASSED, BUT IT ONLY PRINTS THE FIRST MINUTE.

I want to know how to solve this issue, and how does useEffect hooks work in Reactjs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you do not need two useEffect to do this. Follow an example:

```
function DigitalClock() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const date = new Date();
      const formattedTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
      
      setCurrentTime(formattedTime);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return <h2>{currentTime}</h2>;
}
```

Comment: than how will i console log my message? I want to console.log("another minute passed") after every minute passed.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the `useEffect` hook to check if the `seconds` value is divisible by 60 .
you can use this code:

```js
function DigitalClock() {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = React.useState(new Date());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentTime(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    if (seconds % 60 === 0 && seconds !== 0) {
      console.log('Another minute passed');
    }
  }, [currentTime]);

  const formattedTime = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString();

  return <h2>{formattedTime}</h2>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<DigitalClock />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: No it's not working dude, second%60 and second===60 are the same i guess. The real problem is the console.log line execute only once but i want it to run after every minute passed.